# Complex number question concerning the locus of the intersections of the diagonals of a rectangle

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

$P$ is a variable point on the line $x = 4$ and $OPQR$ is a rectangle in which the length of $OP$ is twice the length of $OR.$ If the origin is a stationary point, find the locus of $S$ in Cartesian form, where $S$ is the point of intersection of the diagonals. I have no idea where to start with this question,

I have attempted to use point $P$ as $(4, k)$ and find the length of $OS$ but this has been to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Think of $xy$-plane as the complex plane. Then what you want to find is the complex number $S$. Let $P = 4 + ki$ as you said, when $i = \sqrt{-1}$. OPQR is a rectangle with OP $= 2$ $\times$ OR $=2$ $\times$ PQ. Thus 
\begin{equation}
Q = P \pm P \frac{e^{i\pi/2}}{2}
\end{equation}
where $\pm$ takes into account whether Q is above or below P, $e^{i\pi/2}$ indicates $\pi/2$ rotation, and $\frac{1}{2}$ is the ratio of lengths of the sides of your rectangle.
Now S is the intersection of the diagonals:
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{Q}{2}
\end{equation}
and therefore, considering the fact that $e^{i\pi/2} = i$, we have
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{P}{2}\left(1 \pm \frac{e^{i}}{2}\right) = \frac{4+ki}{2}\left(\frac{2 \pm i}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{4}\left( 8\mp k +(2k \pm 4)i\right)
\end{equation}
that is, in $xy$ coordinate we get
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{8\mp k}{4}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
y = \frac{2k\pm 4}{4}.
\end{equation}
If Q is above P, we choose the upper sign in $\pm$ and $\mp$ and get
\begin{equation}
2x+y = 5
\end{equation}
which is a line. Otherwise, if Q is below P, you get another line:
\begin{equation}
2x-y = 5.
\end{equation}
Note that the two lines are orthogonal! The intersection of these lines is $(\frac{5}{2}, 0)$.

Answer (score 1):

$z=OP=4+it$.

$w=OR=\dfrac12(4+it)e^{\pm i\frac{\pi}{2}}=\pm\dfrac{i}{2}(4+it)$.

We take $+$ ($-$ is similar), so
$$OS=\frac{z+w}{2}=(2-\dfrac{t}{4})+i(1+\dfrac{t}{2})=x+iy$$
after deleting $t$ between them we get $\color{blue}{y=-2x+5}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: with $O$ as the origin, and using $z$ for the complex number associated with point $Z$:

> P is a variable point on the line x = 4

- that's saying $p = 4 + \lambda i\;$ for some $\,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\,$

> and OPQR is a rectangle

- $r = \mu i\,p\;$ for some $\,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$

> in which the length of OP is twice the length of OR

- $|r|=\frac{1}{2}|p| \implies |\mu i \,p| = \frac{1}{2}|p| \implies \mu = \pm\frac{1}{2}$

> where S is the point of intersection of the diagonals

- $s=\frac{1}{2}(p+r)$

Then: $\;s = \cfrac{1}{2}(p \pm \cfrac{1}{2} i \,p) = p \cdot \cfrac{2 \pm i}{4}\,$ which gives the locus as a pair of lines.

---

For the Cartesian form, let $s=x+i\,y\ = (4+\lambda i)\cdot \frac{1}{4}(2\pm i)=\frac{1}{4}(8 \mp \lambda) + i\,\frac{1}{2}(\lambda \pm 2)\,$. The first sign combination gives $x=\frac{1}{4}(8 - \lambda), y=\frac{1}{2}(\lambda + 2)\,$ which, after eliminating $\lambda$ between the two, reduces to $2x+y=5\,$. The second sign combination gives $2x-y=5\,$.